# Angular not performing two way binding for ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have an array of string objects that are in the format of (old,new) values
Eg:

```
this.values= {
  "countByView": {
    "count1": "2(4)",
    "count2": "5(7)",
    "count3": "7(10)"
  }
}
```

As they are string I'm transforming them in HTML using below method while displaying..

```
Old value of count 1 : {{values.countByView.count1.toString().split('(')[0]}}     //output :2
New value of count 1 : {{values.countByView.count1.toString().split('(')[1].slice(0,-1)}})}}  //output:4
```

which works fine.

I was trying to do two way binding with help of a text box 
ie.,

which binds the value of count1 but on change it dosen't get reflected back.

Is this the problem with the ngModel value ?

Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AcNWVrOhXuSxiFDf539J?p=preview)

Comment: did you import the FormsModule in your AppModule?

Comment: Yes I did it in AppModule

Comment: can you share the code for using the the ngModel?

Comment: Sure.I'm creating a fiddle..

Comment: I've added a plunker for your reference.Thanks

Comment: It doesn't work because by using `.split`, you create a new memory reference. This means it doesn't update your variable, but a shadowed one.

Comment: So what can be the possible fix..pls advice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the provided plunker:

you bind the input field with "count1.toString().split('(')[0]"

- when you split the string value it returns a new reference, this means the binding is done on the new reference not no the count1 reference.

in order to fix it, you can define two variables:

```
preCounter = 2;
postCounter = 4;
```

and then you can bind the ngModel to preCounter variable.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="preCounter">
```

============================ EDIT ==============================

new solution:

i've have changed the code you provided in plunker, i did a trick of binding the count to the input field as follow:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-app',
  template: `
    <!-- class gets set here fine - problem with svg? -->
    <h1> Counter: {{count1}} </h1>
    <h1>Old value of count1 : {{count1.toString().split('(')[0]}}</h1>
     <h1>New value of count1 : {{count1.toString().split('(')[1].slice(0,-1)}} </h1>

     //If I change anything inside text box,it's not reflecting in Old value of count1

     <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="preCounter" name="count1" 
        (keyup)="onCountChange()"
     >

  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  color: string = 'red';

  preCounter = 2;
  postCounter = 4;

  count1="2(4)";

  // track the change in the input field
  onCountChange() {
    this.count1 = this.preCounter + `(${this.postCounter})`;
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean to say split the value in the component itself and not in the HTML and bind ?

Comment: yeah you can use two variables to track the counters, this approach is more consistent.

Comment: Sure.As I've  limitations to do that I wanted to try the same in HTMl.Anyways wil check

Comment: i developed the suggested solution. can you please check it